# Increase width of tablerow of dynamically created tablelayout

Tags: android

I have created a table layout in which my table row height is too small, so I want to increase the height of the table row , please guide me table is dynamically created so I don't have any idea.

Code: I have tried to specify  width in Latoutparam integer but not working

```
public void createTableLayout()
{
    String status="Pending";
    TextView txtid=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtcid);
    //TextView txtdate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
    txtid.setText("Customer Id/Name : "+shopnum+"/"+shopname1);
    btnorder1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOrder123);
    btnBack1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack1);
    txtTotalAmount=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTotalAmt);
    btnorder1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {       
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            ShowcOrder1();
            int rcount=(table).getChildCount();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
            for(int r=1;r<rcount;r++)
            {
                TableRow row=(TableRow)table.getChildAt(r);
                int vcount=(row).getChildCount();
            //  String str=
                for(int v1=0;v1<vcount;v1++)
                {
                    TextView tv = (TextView)(((TableRow)row)).getChildAt(v1);


    insertIntoOrderDetails(String.valueOf(orderid),ProdcutId,PackageId,Quantity);
                }
                insertIntoOrder(String.valueOf(orderid), currentDateandTime, shopnum,String.valueOf(roundtotal), sid);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Order Placed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "round: "+roundtotal,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            }

        });

        btnBack1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {   
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });

        //txtdate.setText("Order Date is : "+odate);
            table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbpastorderdetails);
            TableRow tr_heading = new TableRow(Pastorder.this);
            tr_heading.setId(10);
            tr_heading.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr_heading.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView label_product_id = new TextView(Pastorder.this);
            label_product_id.setId(20);
            label_product_id.setText("PID");
            label_product_id.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            //label_question.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            // label_date.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            tr_heading.addView(label_product_id); // add the column to the table row

            //TextView label_question = new TextView(this);
            TextView label_package_id = new TextView(Pastorder.this);
            label_package_id.setId(20);
            label_package_id.setText("  Pack.ID");
            label_package_id.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            //label_question.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            // label_date.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            tr_heading.addView(label_package_id); // add the column to the table row


            //TextView label_question = new TextView(this);
            TextView label_product = new TextView(Pastorder.this);
            label_product.setId(20);
            label_product.setText(" PRODUCT");
            label_product.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            //label_question.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            // label_date.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            tr_heading.addView(label_product); // add the column to the table row
                                                // here
        //  Toast.makeText(ExaminationActivity.this,"hi try ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //TextView label_answer = new TextView(this);
            TextView label_catagory = new TextView(Pastorder.this);
            label_catagory.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
            label_catagory.setText("    CATAGORY"); // set the text for the header
            label_catagory.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); // set the color
            // label_weight_kg.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5); // set the padding (if
            // required)
        //  label_weight_kg.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            tr_heading.addView(label_catagory); // add the column to the table row
                                                    // here


            //TextView label_youranswer = new TextView(this);
            TextView label_package = new TextView(Pastorder.this);
            label_package.setId(20);
            label_package.setText(" PACKAGE");
            label_package.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            //label_question.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            // label_date.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            tr_heading.addView(label_package); // add the column to the table row
                                                // here
            TextView label_weight = new TextView(Pastorder.this);
            label_weight.setId(20);
            label_weight.setText("  WEIGHT");
            label_weight.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            //label_question.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            // label_date.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            tr_heading.addView(label_weight); // add the column to the table row

            TextView label_qty = new TextView(Pastorder.this);
            label_qty.setId(20);
            label_qty.setText(" QUANTITY");
            label_qty.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            //label_question.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            // label_date.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            tr_heading.addView(label_qty); // add the column to the table row

            TextView label_amt = new TextView(Pastorder.this);
            label_amt.setId(20);
            label_amt.setText(" AMOUNT");
            label_amt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            //label_question.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            // label_date.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            tr_heading.addView(label_amt); // add the column to the table row       
            table.addView(tr_heading, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }

public void addRows()
{
    try
    {               
        msaledb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        Cursor allrows  = msaledb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + PRODUCT_TABLE+" WHERE Product_ID = '" + pid +"'", null);
        Cursor allrows1  = msaledb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + PACKAGING_TABLE ,null);
        if(allrows.moveToFirst() && allrows1.moveToFirst())// && allrows1.moveToFirst())
         {         
            int i=1;    
            do
            {   
                tr = new TableRow(Pastorder.this);
                tr.setId(i);
                tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                TextView tvpid = new TextView(Pastorder.this);
                tvpid.setId(11);
                tvpid.setText(""+pid);
                tvpid.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
                tvpid.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tr.addView(tvpid);

                TextView tv_pack_id = new TextView(Pastorder.this);
                tv_pack_id.setId(12);
                tv_pack_id.setText("    "+packid);
                tv_pack_id.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
                tv_pack_id.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tr.addView(tv_pack_id);

                TextView tv = new TextView(Pastorder.this);
                tv.setId(1);
                tv.setText("    "+allrows.getString(2));
                tv.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tr.addView(tv);
                TextView tv1 = new TextView(Pastorder.this);
                tv1.setId(2);
                tv1.setText("   "+allrows.getString(3));
                tv1.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
                tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tr.addView(tv1);
                do
                {
                if(allrows1.getString(1).trim().equals(packid.trim()) && allrows1.getString(2).trim().equals(pid.trim()))
                {
//                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+allrows1.getString(2).trim(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+p_id.get(0).trim(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        TextView tv2 = new TextView(Pastorder.this);
                        tv2.setId(3);
                        tv2.setText("   "+allrows1.getString(3));
                        tv2.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
                        tv2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        tr.addView(tv2);                        
                        TextView tv3 = new TextView(Pastorder.this);
                        tv3.setId(4);
                        tv3.setText("   "+allrows1.getString(4));
                        tv3.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
                        tv3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        tr.addView(tv3);                        
                        TextView tv4 = new TextView(Pastorder.this);
                        tv4.setId(4);
                        tv4.setText("   "+qty);
                        tv4.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
                        tv4.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        tr.addView(tv4);                        
                        TextView tv5 = new TextView(Pastorder.this);
                        tv5.setId(4);
                        tv5.setText("   "+Integer.parseInt(allrows1.getString(6).trim())*Integer.parseInt(qty.trim()));
                        tv5.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
                        tv5.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        tr.addView(tv5);

                }
                }while(allrows1.moveToNext());

                table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                i++;
                tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+tr.getId(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        tr1=(TableRow)view; //assign selected TableRow gobally
                        registerForContextMenu(tr1);
                        openContextMenu(tr1);
                    }
                });

            }while(allrows.moveToNext());

           }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in search", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: post the code you are using to create the table

Comment: I have posted my code do suggest me something if you have any ideas thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TableRow layout parameters must be wrap content. Instead of trying to expand the row in order to fit your needs, try to manually set the appropriate layout parameters in the views that are inside the TableRow object. Wrap content or fill parent won't work, try playing around with actual density pixels.

Hope this helps